# How to solve a 4th order nonnegative LASSO problem?

Tags: optimization, constrained-optimization, nonconvex

I need to solve the following 4th order nonnegative LASSO problem:
$$
\min_{x \geq 0} \quad || |Ax|^2 - b ||^2 + \lambda ||x||_1
$$
where $|\cdot|^2$ denotes element-wise squared. $A$ is small size (e.g., $A \in \mathbb{R}^{100\times100}$).

This problem is non-convex and I worry about the convergence and stucking at saddle points.

**My efforts**

Split the original problem as following:
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \min_{x \geq 0, \, y} & &  || |y|^2 - b ||^2 + \lambda ||x||_1
\\
& \,\,\,\,\text{s.t.} & & y = Ax 
\end{aligned}
$$
Then the optimization can be done using primal-dual algorithms (e.g. Chambolle-Pock's), resulting two updating sub-steps:

- $x$-update is a nonnegative LASSO problem which is solvable (given $y$ estimation $\hat{y}$):

  $$
    \min_{x\geq 0} \quad \mu || Ax - \hat{y} ||^2 + \lambda ||x||_1
    $$
- $y$-update is a 4th order element-wise problem, and can be solved via exhaustive search or Newton's method, yet the convergence is unknown to me (given $x$ estimation $\hat{x}$):

  $$
    \min_{y} \quad || |y|^2 - b ||^2 + \mu || y - A\hat{x} ||^2
    $$

**Issues**

- My implementation does not converge; as well as for the proximal gradient descent. From my numerical experiments it seems the initial point plays a very, very important role.
- Therefore, this approach it is unclear if we can end up with a point sufficiently closes to the optimal.

**Question**

I wonder if there are other approaches for this problem. Provable efficient methods are preferrable.

Comment: Do you have an example with values for $b$, $A$ and $\lambda$?

Comment: @nicoguaro If I understand it correctly you are asking for a specific numerical example. Sorry I do not have one. (In fact for my practical engineering scenes only $A$ is controllable) For my case $A$ could be a circular matrix (i.e. diagonalizable in Fourier domain). For now $A$ can be assumed as a Laplacian matrix with stencil $-1, 2, -1$. And there’s no specific requirements for other variables.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. If you don't have those parameters how can you say that you don't have convergence?

Comment: @nicoguaro well i thought math was enough. I could have provided one of my real data here if you want it. (This question will be edited later)

Answer (score 2):

I guess a problem with this approach is that it also "sparsifies" the gradient.
If you look at the objective function:

\begin{align}
\Phi(x) = \lvert|(Ax)\odot(Ax)-b |\rvert^2+\lambda\lvert|x|\rvert_1
\end{align}

If one uses a proximal gradient method, we have

\begin{align}
x_{k+1} = \mathcal{P}\left(x_k-\alpha A^T\left(\left((Ax_k)\odot(Ax_k)-b\right)\odot(Ax_k)\right)\right)
\end{align}

With $\mathcal{P}$ being the projection onto a scaled L1 ball and $\alpha$ being the step size. The important part to point out is the $\odot (Ax_k)$ at the end of the expression. If $x_k$ is shrinked, it reduces the gradient strength in the region/near where it was shrinked. So if $x_k$ becomes sparse, there may be region where the gradient becomes extremely small. Then you might be stuck and can't converge to the global minimum anymore.

That can also make a problem if the kernel has certain properties. E.g suppose the input $x$ has a region that is more or less constant. This region would yield a very low $Ax$ if the kernel for a convolution is antisymmetric. As a consequence, the gradient would also be very small, even though a large chunk of $x$ could be located there.